# Unique day of the year

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, time

I made this challenge.

Astronomers announced that the sky and the moon will appear violet-velvet next week, and one of their workmates is also celebrating her birthday on the day that the moon will appear violet-velvet. Also, they announced that an asteroid will approach close to Earth on that day.

What they observed about the day when moon will appear violet-velvet:

- the date format of that day is form of: $M/D/YYY\color{blue}{\textrm{Y}}$, where $\color{Blue}{\textrm{Y}}$ is equal to the adjacent number to $D$, and when written in $M/D/YYYY$ format, $MDYYYY$ is a perfect square and it’s square root is form of $ABC$, where the tens digit $B$ corresponds to the product of $A$ and $C$.
- It is the (duo deducted from **triple of number of months in a year**)th day of the year.
- (Perfect number) of days before that day is Chinese New Year and the day is $M/DD$, where $MDD$ is when (**Octal** is **cubed**) and **divided into quadruple** pieces.
- Ash Wednesday will fall after **quadruple!** of days from the day when moon will appear violet-velvet.

When and what day of the week when moon will appears as violet-velvet and an Asteroid will approach close to earth?

Hint:

> The day when the moon will appear violet-velvet is not a working day, nor it is a weekday. But it is not also holiday in the U.S.

> The first two digits of the year is equal to Month and Day.

> (Half of gross plus half of dozen minus one) years after that year is a square number year.

> The tens digit of that year is equal to the month.

Bonus question:

What is the name of their workmate whose birthday falls on the day when moon will appear violet-velvet?

Hint:

> They remember the first three words of the **3rd month of the year**, but the words was **swapped by Artificial Intelligence**.

Bonus question:

What time this phenomenon will occur:

Hint:

> The $HH:MM$ will correspond to the colored text below:

> It will occur exactly **twice** hours after the **$\color{violet}{\textrm{great gross}}$**

Answer (score 1):

The date is

> **2/3/2324** - which is the **Sunday 3rd of February 2324**

---

For the requirements:

> - 232324 is 482 squared, and 8 is 4 * 2
> - It is the 34th day of the year (3 * 12 - 2 = 34)
> - The [Chinese New Year in 2324](https://chinese-year.com/2324) is apparently the 27th January, although OP was looking for the 28th, which is 1/28 (8^3 / 4 = 128), and also 6 days (a perfect number) before
> - [Ash Wednesday in 2324](https://calendar.center/gb/9/2324/ash-wednesday/) is February 27th, 24 days after (4!)

For the hints:

> - Sunday is not a working day or a weekday
> - The first two digits of the year are indeed equal to the month and day: 2 and 3
> - 77 years after 2324 is 2401, which is 49^2
> - The tens digit of the year is 2, equal to the month

For the bonus questions:

> Apparently [Elmo's birthday is February 3rd](https://www.google.com/search?q=elmo%27s+birthday&oq=Elmo%27s+Birthday&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqDAgAEAAYQxiABBiKBTIMCAAQABhDGIAEGIoFMgcIARAAGIAEMgcIAhAAGIAEMgcIAxAAGIAEMgcIBBAAGIAEMgcIBRAAGIAEMgcIBhAAGIAEMggIBxAAGBYYHjIICAgQABgWGB4yCAgJEAAYFhge0gEHMzY1ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), so Elmo? Not sure on the hint though

And for the time:

> A great gross is 1728, so two hours after that is **19:28**

Comment: I looked but couldn't find anywhere whether the moon will actually appear purple on this date, or if an asteroid will actually pass by earth either